# Не получается скрыть fab в активити из фрагмента

Tags: android, recyclerview

Хочу сделать скрытие fab из фрагмента который находится в контейнере в активити. Сама кнопка находится в активити и я хочу ее скрывать когда прокручиваю recyclerView. В фрагменте добавил слушатель изменения состояния списка:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                MainCenter mainCenter = new MainCenter();

                if (dy > 0) {
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", "scroll up");
                    mainCenter.changeButtonVisibility(false);
                } else if (dy < 0) {
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", "scroll down");
                    mainCenter.changeButtonVisibility(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

и дальше вот функция в активити для скрывания кнопки:

```
public void changeButtonVisibility(boolean visibility){
        if(visibility){
            Log.w("MY_TAG", "visible");
            fab_next_jobs.show();
        }else{
            Log.w("MY_TAG", "invisible");
            fab_next_jobs.hide();
        }
    }
```

логи пишутся нормально, при прокручивании списка все пишется правильно, а при попытке скрыть кнопку, получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.hide()' on a null object reference
```

не могу понять в чем проблема, вроде кнопка работает, а при прокручивании списка приложение летит.

Comment: Предположу, что `recyclerView` находится во фрагменте, а `MainCenter` - это класс активити в котором находится сам фрагмент. Тогда непонятно, почему вы создаете еще один экземпляр `MainCenter` при прокрутке списка?

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, вы все правильно предположили, но как тогда правильно поступить в текущей ситуации?

Comment: Легкий и не совсем правильный способ - получить активити `(MainCenter)getActivity()`, но, фрагменты живут дольше активити и можно получить NPE, да и утечки памяти возможны. Тут нужно побольше почитать про взаимодействие фрагментов и активити.

Comment: но вообще реально сделать то что я хочу из фрагмента, или нужно как-то по-другому пробовать и искать?

Comment: Реализовать конечно реально, просто я не совсем понимаю всей задачи. Первое. что приходит на ум - из активити подписаться на событие прокрутки, во фрагменте генерировать событие и отдавать подписчикам. Это один из вариантов, возможно можно совсем по-другому спроектировать.

Comment: суть в том что это список сообщений, и есть кнопка, которая отвечает за написание нового письма, и я хочу ее скрывать когда список сообщений прокручивается

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить главное Activity из фрагмента.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
FloatingActionButton fab;
...
}

MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
main.fab.hide();
```